# How to manage CheckBox in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, syncfusion

I am a beginner in programming. I want to manage my Checkbox by including "if-else-condition" in it. For examples, there are two columns in my grid which are named "readable" and "writable" (public bool). I will use CheckBox for these two columns.

1) the CheckBox will be "read-only", if the value of readable/writable is false.

2) the CheckBox are editable by the user, if the value of readable/writable is true.

For example, how can I edit from the code below? (assuming that I have done my data-binding)

```
<sf:GridTreeColumn MappingName="Readable" PercentWidth="2">
    <sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
        <sf:GridStyleInfo CellType="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="False"/>
    </sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
</sf:GridTreeColumn>
<sf:GridTreeColumn MappingName="Writable" PercentWidth="2">
    <sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
        <sf:GridStyleInfo CellType="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="False"/>
    </sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
</sf:GridTreeColumn>
```

Sincere thanks to all who try to read my question and try to help me. =)

Comment: Hi, Are you using third part controls?? I guess you are using syncfusion controls

Comment: What is your underlying Data? What is the DataContext of StyleInfo?

Comment: Nope. I am not using third part controls. Actually now i am thinking will it be solved if i use DataBoundTemplate for my CellType. Then I do data-binding to the properties "IsEnabled" and "IsChecked" of my CheckBox

Comment: You Should bind the ReadOnly of the GridStyleInfo to the Writeable property of your data.

Comment: E.g. ReadOnly="{Binding Writable}"

Comment: Then, what is that sf:GridTreeColumn control

Comment: sf is actually syncfusion. Erm.. I think I will edit my questions again to make it clearer. Thank you guys so much for the reply.. I am reading now one by one, and it really does help a lot =)

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm currently a student and still new to programming. =(

Comment: Error appeared when I tried to bind Writable Property to ReadOnly. It stated that ReadOnly is not a dependency property and can't be binded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Syncfusion controls you have a property get it from syncfusion.GridCommon.wpf. to set check box inside your column

```
<sf:GridTreeColumn MappingName="Readable" PercentWidth="2">
<sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
    <sf:GridStyleInfo CellType="CheckBox" gridCommon:VisualContainer.WantsMouseInput=true HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="False"/>
</sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
```

Try this!

Comment: What does "gridCommon:VisualContainer.WantsMouseInput" mean?

Comment: Are you using syncfusion(third party) controls for GridTree??

Comment: I see.. Syncfusion means third party. Yea i added Syncfusion to my reference and use it in my xaml codes. Sorry im currently a student and still new to it. =(

Comment: In Syncfusion common dll they provide the API for your requirement, that's I am explaining in this answer.

Comment: You need to add the namespace for the Syncfusion.GridCommon.Wpf.dll as gridCommon in xaml and you can access the VisualContainer.WantsMouseInput and set it as true for get your requirement.

Comment: I got what you meant now, gridCommon is the name I gave to the namespace I have added.

Comment: Hi Ravi, adding "xmlns:gridCommon="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.GridCommon.Wpf.dll" is correct right?

I have two errors during compilation
1) The name "VisualContainer" does not exist in the namespace "*as stated*".
2) The attachable property 'WantsMouseInput' was not found in type 'VisualContainer'.

Thank you so much for your time again.

Comment: you can refer this by accessing this site http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/wpf/grid/html/82af5bcd-a08c-42a7-1e4a-a6d0115c484a.htm

Comment: Check once the Syncfusion.GridCommon.Wpf dll is attached with your project

Comment: If you feel this as answer please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by using the convertes:
Add this class in your project and include it in your XAML code

```
 public sealed class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Methods

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        bool boolValue = false;

        if (!bool.TryParse(System.Convert.ToString(value), out boolValue))
        {
            boolValue = false;
        }

        if (boolValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    #endregion


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<sf:GridTreeColumn MappingName="Readable" PercentWidth="2">
<sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
    <sf:GridStyleInfo CellType="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   
 IsThreeState="False" IsEnabled="{Binding Readable, Converter={StaticResource  
 BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
 </sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
 </sf:GridTreeColumn>
 <sf:GridTreeColumn MappingName="Writable" PercentWidth="2">
 <sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
 <sf:GridStyleInfo CellType="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 

 IsThreeState="False" IsEnabled="{Binding Writable, Converter={StaticResource   
 BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
 </sf:GridTreeColumn.StyleInfo>
 </sf:GridTreeColumn>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Praveena, your idea of converter sounds cool. I'm currently trying this. But, "IsEnabled is not recognised or is not accessible". Perhaps is something miss out?

Comment: It stated "The Property 'IsEnabled' was not found in type 'GridStyleInfo'"

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with the sync fusion controls, just figure out what is the equivalent of IsEnabled for your control and use it instead. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not directly answer your question, enabling and disabling the checkbox on button clicks may give you the desired outcome of having the ability to make the checkbox either read only or read/write.

(**Note:** This simple, yet effective concept can be altered and used in loading events or authentication of users, disabling or enabling particular pieces of content on an application, which may be useful to you in the future.)

```
        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```